# wpf datagrid xaml and entity framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml

I want to display in a Column navigation property like city_Name 
I wrote this code but Nothing happens

```
      <DataGrid Margin="210,15"  Grid.Row="1" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dg_Super" RowHeight="20" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Super Name"   Binding="{Binding Path=SupermarketName, Mode=OneTime}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="City"  Binding="{Binding Path=City1.CityName, Mode=OneTime}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

and the the c# code

```
            var super = mh.Supermarkets;
            dg_Super.ItemsSource = super.ToList();
```

City1 is anavigation property from ef model.
Please what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query - perhaps add the Include method:

```
var super = mh.Supermarkets.Include("City1")
```

Because EF doens't know it has to get data from the "City" table. If the query uses a field from the City table, you don't have to include `Include("City")` - EF can then detect that you need data from the table, thus it automaticly loads the City table

Comment: you are very welcome - plz mark the answer as correnct- thanks